# Given $\mathfrak{q}$ in $L/K$ unramified, can we find $\alpha$ such that $L=K(\alpha)$ and $f'(\alpha)$ not divisible by $\mathfrak{q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the following situation: Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of number fields and $\mathfrak{q}$ a prime of $L$ that is unramified. I am looking for a proof of the fact that one can always find some primitive element $\alpha$ of the field extension with the following property: If $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $f'(\alpha)\mathcal{O}_L$ is not divisible by $\mathfrak{q}$ - in other words, reducing everything mod $\mathfrak{q}$, $\overline{\alpha}$ is not a repeated root of $\overline{f}$.

I know that this is true "most of the time". Namely, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is the prime of $K$ below $\mathfrak{q}$, in the case where we can find some $\alpha$ with $L=K(\alpha)$ such that the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$ is coprime to $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L$. However, this might not always be possible.

If it is indeed true, **I would like to have a "global" proof** of this fact, i.e. without localization.

(Background: I am trying to give a fairly simple proof that unramified primes $\mathfrak{q}$ do not divide the different $\mathcal{D}_{L/K}$. If one can always find an $\alpha$ as above, the argument is simple: We know $f'(\alpha)\in\mathcal{D}_{L/K}$ and hence $\mathcal{D}_{L/K}|f'(\alpha)\mathcal{O}_L$, which shows that $\mathcal{D}_{L/K}$ is not divisible by $\mathfrak{q}$.)

Comment: Perhaps you can carry over the proof of Theorem 4.8 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf from the setting of base field $\mathbf Q$ to a general number field as a base field without using localization.   The main technical point is being able to speak about ${\rm Tr}_{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha) \bmod p$ as ${\rm Tr}_{(\mathcal O_K/(p))/\mathbf F_p}(\alpha \bmod (p))$ for $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$.  Then you don't need to use the crutch of rings analogous to $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$.

Comment: @KCd Maybe this can be made to work, but a major obstacle lies in the fact that at some point, it is used there that $\operatorname{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}(\alpha)$. This is straightforward since $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but in general $\mathcal{O}_L$ is not a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, so even defining what $\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K}(\alpha)$ is non-trivial - apparently, however, this can be done via localization (see for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278291/what-are-traces).

Comment: That is why in my comment I had jumped from ${\rm Tr}_{K/\mathbf Q}$ directly to ${\rm Tr}_{(\mathcal O_K/(p))/\mathbf F_p}$ without mentioning an intermediate step that uses ${\rm Tr}_{\mathcal O_K/\mathbf Z}$.  Perhaps there could be a way of making that leap without bringing in  ${\rm Tr}_{\mathcal O_K/\mathbf Z}$. I'm not saying I know how to do that (without using localization).  Did you post your question just for the sake of curiosity? I think studying the relative setting of number fields is a very good excuse to *use* localization, since that's where it really shows its power.

Comment: Well, I worked through some exercises in Marcus' book "Number Fields" and there it is proved that ramified primes divide the different with purely global arguments. Hence, I was trying to find a proof of the converse (i.e. primes dividing the different are ramified) which is also in the spirit of this global approach (I am aware, however, that this is most commonly proved by local methods).

Comment: I was thinking of Marcus' book when I commented on the usefulness of localization, as I know he specifically addresses the lack of that approach in his book.  Let me pull the book off my shelf to quote what he wrote in the introduction: "Any awkwardness therein can be taken by the reader as motivation to learn about localization."  So there you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{p} =\mathfrak{q}\cap O_K$, $R=O_L/\mathfrak{p}O_L$, $k=O_K/\mathfrak{p}$, $\mathfrak{p}O_L=\mathfrak{q} I$.

$\mathfrak{q}$ unramified means that $I\not\subset \mathfrak{q}$ ie. $(\mathfrak{q},I)=(1)$ and $$R \cong O_L/\mathfrak{q}\times O_L/I\quad \text{   as } k \text{ algebra}\tag{1}$$

- Take $\beta\in I$ whose reduction generates $O_L/\mathfrak{q}$ as a field extension of $k$.
- Take $\gamma\in O_L$ that is a primitive element $L=\Bbb{Q}(\gamma)$.
- Let $$\alpha=\beta+n\gamma |R|$$ where $n$ is large enough such that $\forall \sigma,\sigma'\in Hom_\Bbb{Q}(L,\Bbb{C}), n |R||\sigma(\gamma)-\sigma'(\gamma)| > |\sigma(\beta)-\sigma'(\beta)|$.

  This implies that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has $[L:\Bbb{Q}]$ distinct complex embeddings ie. $L=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=K(\alpha)$.

Let $f(x)\in O_K[x]$ be $\alpha$'s monic minimal polynomial. Using $(1)$ we have
$$f(x) = \det(x-\alpha\in End_K(L))\equiv \det(x-\alpha\in End_k(R))\in k[x]$$
$$ = \det(x-\alpha\in End_k(O_L/\mathfrak{q}))\ \det(x-\alpha\in End_k(O_L/I))$$
$$= \det(x-\beta\in End_k(O_L/\mathfrak{q}))\ \det(x-0\in End_k(O_L/I)) = h(x) x^m\in k[x]$$
where $h(x)\in k[x]$ is separable and irreducible of degree $\dim_k(O_L/\mathfrak{q})$ and $m=\dim_k(O_L/I)$.

Comment: Interesting. There is this famous example by Dedekind of cubic field where $2$ divides the index of every element. How does this not contradict your argument ?

Comment: $h(x)x^m$ is not separable! Dedekind proves that your cubic field $E$ is not monogenic because the $\Bbb{Q}$ minimal polynomial of any element in $O_E$ is never separable $\bmod 2$ whereas (every prime above) $2$ is unramified in $O_E$. Here if $K=\Bbb{Q},\mathfrak{p}=p$ then we should have $(O_L:O_K[\alpha])=p^m \bmod p^{m+1}$.

Comment: Very nice! I was trying to lift some primitve element of $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{p}$, but obviously, you have to be careful how to do it.

Comment: @mxian Did you mean $O_L/\mathfrak{q}$? The main point is that there is sometimes no primitive element of $O_L/\mathfrak{p}O_L$ (that's Dedekind's example of a cubic field unramified at $2$)

Comment: @reuns Yes, sorry, I meant to say $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathfrak{q}$.